How to setup the arrays to perfom fft at once?
I am trying to understand how to setup the arrays efficiently to peform the FFT at once.
There are Lt samples for each Theta and each samples is of type complex 3d-vector.
std::complex<double> x_coefficients[Lt];
std::complex<double> y_coefficients[Lt];
std::complex<double> z_coefficients[Lt];

After populating the samples I perform the FFT like
status = DftiCreateDescriptor(&forward_handle, DFTI_DOUBLE, DFTI_COMPLEX, 1, (Lt));
status = DftiSetValue(forward_handle, DFTI_FORWARD_SCALE, (sqrt(2.0 * pi) / static_cast<double>(lt_child)));
status = DftiCommitDescriptor(forward_handle);

status = DftiComputeForward(forward_handle, x_coefficients);
status = DftiComputeForward(forward_handle, y_coefficients);
status = DftiComputeForward(forward_handle, z_coefficients);

I don't really think this way is an efficient way even for one Theta and there are Lg Theta and M unknows.
Any help will be appreciated.

